# I get an error when using the custom arrow foo in the pgf documentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm working on defining a new arrow.  I read through the documentation, and decided to make small changes to move from the existing foo definition to my custom arrow definition.

However, I have a problem.  When I try to compile the code from the manual (section 1004, page 1020 of the 3.0.1a manual), I get the following error:

`Missing number, treated as zero.`

I'd like help understanding the cause of the error, as well as some suggestions about how to troubleshoot such errors on my own.

MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = foo,
  parameters = { \the\pgfarrowlength },
  setup code = {
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
% The hull
\pgfarrowshullpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt} \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength} \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength} % Saves: Only the length:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code = {
    \pgfpathmoveto{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}
    \pgfpathlineto{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfpathlineto{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}
    \pgfpathlineto{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
},
  defaults = { length = 4cm }
}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-foo] (0,0) -- (8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I've edited the question to use `article` instead of minimal.  And I've added a section and page reference to the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reporting this as a bug in the documentation. I'm guessing that it should be something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfdeclarearrow{%
  name=foo,
  parameters={%
    \the\pgfarrowlength
  },
  setup code={%
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
    % The hull
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    % Saves: Only the length:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code={%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
  },
  defaults={%
    length=4cm,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [-foo] (0,0) -- (8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: de-bugged arrow]